# Trigger issues (multiple events, enter/exit)

Tags: unity, c#

not sure if this is a scripting issue or if I've implemented something wrong with the colliders, but here it goes:

All I want is a simple platform trigger that registers when the player steps on it and when they get leave.
I have BoxColliders with IsTrigger on both the platform and the player and in general everything works okay.

However there are some strange edge cases where the OnTriggerExit happens immediately after the OnTriggerEnter. Once I've even managed to stand in a place where it *constantly* went from Enter to Exit to Enter etc. without the player moving at all!

So I put position outputs in the debug text and the positions of where the Enter/Exit happens is in really strange places, nowhere near the trigger volume!
[image]

Initially I put a cooldown on the trigger volume, so it could only trigger every second but that doesn't solve the issue of the Exit triggering for some reason when it shouldn't.

Here's my code for the platform:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collider player;
    public Material activeMaterial, inactiveMaterial;
    public float TriggerVolumeCooldown = 1f;

    private Renderer m_Renderer;
    private bool m_IsOnCooldown;
    private float m_CooldownStartTimestamp;


void Start()
{
    m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    m_Renderer.material = inactiveMaterial;
    m_IsOnCooldown = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider == player && !m_IsOnCooldown)
    {
        print(" Player entered " + collider.name + " CD: " + m_IsOnCooldown + " xyz: " + collider.GetComponentInParent<Transform>().position);
        m_Renderer.material = activeMaterial;
        m_IsOnCooldown = true;
        m_CooldownStartTimestamp = Time.time;
    }
    else
    {
        print("cooldown");
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
{
    //i++;
    if (collider == player)
    {
        print(" Player left " + collider.name + " xyz: " + collider.GetComponentInParent<Transform>().position);
        m_Renderer.material = inactiveMaterial;
    }
}



void Update()
{
    if (m_IsOnCooldown)
    {
        if (Time.time - m_CooldownStartTimestamp > TriggerVolumeCooldown)
        {
            m_IsOnCooldown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How tight/ much extend they over the actual body?

Comment: Is this more of a "player is in an invisible the area" or more of a "player touches a solid object" scenario? In the latter case, it is usually more appropriate to use OnCollisionEnter / Exit (note the different method signature, that the object needs to be static (or have a rigidbody) and that the player needs a rigidbody)

Comment: How do you move your player.at present?

Comment: The collider is the same size as the body capsule. But I also tried making it really small since I thought that might have been the issue. Essentially, I tried different sizes.@Zibelas

Comment: This is a "play enters invisible area", here the player steps on a platform to trigger something. @Philipp

Comment: The player object uses a Character Controller @DMGregory

Comment: @cbfunky How did you configure the collider of the platform and of the player? (settings, position and dimension would be interesting)

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to post images in the comment, but there is nothing special about the colliders. Both the player and platform collider have "istrigger" checked and no material set. I've tried a variety of position and dimensions on the player - on the platform the center is 0,25,0 and pos 0.9,50,0.9. I also tried removing the IsTrigger on the player (apparently it doesn't need it in this scenario) but that also didn't change anything.